# track MKMapView networking connection?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

is it possible to know when the map has fully loaded all of its data (I know u can with other connections) and then perform some action? Basically I want to do a task only if and when the map has fully loaded and not with the grey squares that show with poor network signal?

Many thanks

Jules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the appropriate methods of the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol:

```
– mapViewWillStartLoadingMap:
– mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:
– mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:withError:
```

Comment: Sorry,

Didnt even check the dels. Thanks for the quick response.

Mods delete this post if u feel the need.